# How to get xpath text from element but exclude some of it based on class?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

How can I get the text "Show ME, and Show me too" using xpath expression?  I need the "OMIT ME" omitted.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<span class="omitME">OMIT ME</span>
Show ME, and
<span class="showME"> Show me too</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the relevant XSLT code too?  We need to know what context you're starting from, and also what version of XSLT you're working with.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "get". Do you want the XSLT stylesheet to output the text you mentioned? And is it really necessary that the work is all done in XPath? or do you mean to use match patterns as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XPath, you could use:

```
/table/tr/td//text()[not(parent::span[@class='omitME'])]
```

to select all text nodes descendants of the `td` element, except those whose parent is a `span` of the 'omitME' class.

Or perhaps:

```
//text()[not(parent::span[@class='omitME'])]
```

to select all text nodes descendants of the root node - again, except those whose parent is an "omitted" `span`.

In XSLT, you would probably use something else, depending on the current context and on the purpose of the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way:

```
<xsl:template match="td | span[@class='showME']">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="span[@class='omitME']"/>
```

Comment: The OP actually asked for an XPath expression, though it's hard to tell if he really meant to exclude match patterns.

Comment: I am not sure how you interpreted the question, but surely the first template is redundant?

Comment: @LarsH you're right.  My answer assumes silently that the presence of the XSLT tag is correct, and the mention of XPath is a symptom of OP's confusion and may be ignored.  I could be wrong.

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes, it is redundant.  Making the first template explicit here is just a way of allowing OP to defer a fuller understanding of default templates until later, and focus for now on how the different match patterns lead to the desired behavior.  (When I am learning new languages, I often find it helpful to specify default values explicitly until I am so solid in my understanding of what is going on that they no longer help.  Then I start omitting them.  I used full XPath syntax and avoided the short forms for years.  Other learners likely differ.)